# Can roslyn syntax tree be converted to xml file?

Tags: roslyn, roslyn-code-analysis

Syntax visualizer is really good for understanding the code. Bu i want to see  the syntax tree in an xml file. Is there any solution for visualizing it by xml ?

Comment: Write a SyntaxVisitor that produces `XElement`s?

Comment: You can write code to produce any output code can produce